# WSO2 EI 6.3.0 - Jms, vfs, mailto and local transports don't work within any tenants except carbon.super

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have tried to use these 4 types of transfers in my proxy services in my tenant and none of them don't work. They work fine in carbon.super but don't work in any created tenant. There aren't any exceptions or errors in log file of EI. Do I need to change some settings for tenants?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Managing+Tenant-specific+Subscriptions) to configure a tenant specific JMS proxy service with WSO2 Message Broker.

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Managing+Tenant-specific+Subscriptions) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Managing+Tenant-specific+Subscriptions